# How to detect digits from images using pytesseract?

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect the text from the images
but fail due to some unknown reasons.

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image
import re
image = Image.open('sample.jpg')
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 7 outbase digits'
number = pt.image_to_string(image, config=custom_config)
print('Number: ', number)
```

```
Number:  0 50 100 200 250 # This is the output that I am getting.
```

```
Expected --> 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,8
```

Comment: Hi @scee welcome to SO! You mention that the conversion fails. Can you provide some more details as to what error messages (if any) you got?  What is your OS ?

Comment: @vvy, I am using macos. The conversion is not necessary fail but it's producing the wrong output. I will update the question.

Comment: before sending it to tesseract, try use some morphological operations such as thresholding. tesseract works better in black/white images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCR using tesseract on crude/raw image inputs might not give you expected result.
For the given image, a somewhat better result can be obtained using *grayscale* conversion followed by *thresholding* operation

[image]

To perform the conversion and thresholding operation you may use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) as follows:

```
$ convert input_image.jpg -colorspace gray grayscale_image.jpg
$ convert grayscale_image.jpg -threshold 45% thresholded_image.jpg
$ convert thresholded_image.jpg -morphology Dilate Rectangle:4,3 dilated_binary.jpg
$ python run_tesseract.py
 00000109
```

A more robust approach to OCR is via training the tesseract engine [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352918/how-do-i-train-tesseract-4-with-image-data-instead-of-a-font-file)

Comment: Thank you @vvy. I am wondering if there is a way to execute in just python file.

Comment: In that case, **OpenCV** will help you achieve the same. [Something like this](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/#preprocessingfortesseract)